# Insert JSON File in SAP Analytics Cloud Custom Widgets

Tags: json, custom-widgets, sap-analytics-cloud

While I wanted to upload a JSON file in SAP Analytics Cloud in the Custom Widgets area, the following error message appears:

> Default value of property value is expected to be of type number
>
> [image]

Do you know the reason for this error?

Comment: give the structure of your json

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given either wrong data type in your JSON file or wrong value.

If you have provided datatype as number then give integer value.

```
"value": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": "Gauge value",
            "default": 0
        }
```

If you have given your datatype as string then give string value.

```
"info": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Gauge info",
            "default": ""
        }
```

I think this will solve your issue.